# Open-source radix/mtrie implementation in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I intend to use **RADIX / MTRIE** as my preferred data-structure for a routing implementation.

Is there a decent open source implementation available (apart from freebsd-net) which I can use for my purpose, or do I need to write one myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a radix-tree implementation available under the GNU General Public License version 2, or (at your option) any later version:

http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/lxr/source/lib/radix-tree.c

Answer (score 0):

If you cant find anything else, you can always port this [**java version from Google Code**.](http://code.google.com/p/radixtree/)